# Facebook user ID may change after upgrade?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, scope

I have a facebook app version `1.0`, now this app returns the global `ID`, but after April 30 will automatically upgrade to 2.0.

I want to know, if after April 30, customers have logged this facebook app previously but erased and then log back this app then it returns the global ID (as above) or app `scope ID` ?

Answer (score -1):

As pointed out by Igy, it will return the same ID regardless of whether or not they deauthorized and reauthorized the application.

Comment: That's incorrect - if a user removes your app and re-adds it you should get the same ID as when they signed up originally

Comment: You're from Facebook so you're obviously right.  Could this have been a bug when things first came out that was resolved?  I had an issue with this when I first started using them.  Some of my user's data was under a different Facebook ID than their original logs indicated.  I edited my answer to reflect your post.

Comment: Yes, there was a bug where it wasn't correctly tracking when a user removed your app (for the purposes of remembering which ID you should receive if they log in again at a later time), but AFAIK that's long-resolved
For users you know about via some other means (a friend of one of your users, for example) but never logged into your app, it's not expected to get their canonical / 'original' UID if they login to your app

Comment: Thanks, yes it was only an issue when I first converted my apps over.